# How to recursively search nodes while ignoring HTML tags of child nodes

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a script to search and highlight hashtags on any HTML page, it is working very good on text nodes but I'm having troubles to make this work also when HTML tags or special characters are involved in the page, e.g. I want that in the following line:

```
 and also  #<div class="someclass">HashTwo</div>
```

Both hastags will be highlighted. Issue is that my code is recursive so the second hash in the above example is separated into a node and chilNnode and therefore not captured by the Regexp.

Here is my script, any help is appreciated!

```
function SearchHilight()
{
  var targetNode = document.body;
  var skipTags = new RegExp("^(?:SPAN|SCRIPT)$");
  var matchRegex = new RegExp("( ]+)", "i");

  this.hilightResults = function(node)
  {
    if(node === undefined || !node) return;
    if(skipTags.test(node.nodeName)) return;

    if(node.hasChildNodes()) {
      for(var i=0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
        this.hilightResults(node.childNodes[i]);

    }
    if(node.nodeType == 3) { // NODE_TEXT
      if((nv = node.nodeValue) && (regs = matchRegex.exec(nv))) {
        var match = document.createElement('SPAN');
        match.setAttribute("content", regs[0]);
        match.appendChild(document.createTextNode(regs[0]));
        match.style.backgroundColor = "            match.style.fontStyle = "inherit";
        match.style.color = "    
        var after = node.splitText(regs.index);
        after.nodeValue = after.nodeValue.substring(regs[0].length);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(match, after);
      }
    };
  };

this.apply = function()
  {
    this.hilightResults(targetNode);
  };

var thisSearch; 

thisSearch = new SearchHilight();
thisSearch.apply();
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) - when you **fully** understand it, then you may continue

Comment: I updated the title of this question. I don't expect the resolution to be with additional Regexp tweak, but I wish to keep the regexp search as per above code